# AFNetworking - iOS Getting JSON When PHP Prints It

Tags: ios, json, content-type, afnetworking

I have just started using AFNetworking, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the following to work.

My URL points to a PHP file which has printed out data it retrieved from a database as JSON, but with AFNetworking I get the "Expected Content Type" error.

My code is the following but with a different URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/json.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation 
JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [json valueForKeyPath:@"results"]);
                        } failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

Comment: You web server is probably sending the wrong MIME type in the response (i.e. "text/plain" instead of "application/json").  What is the full text of the "Expected Content Type" error you are getting?

Comment: Try to send a `Get` request to your URL with any REST client (use a Firefox add-on if you don't have any other preferred) and see what is the `Content-Type` header value returned.

Comment: it is text/html. How would I go about changing this for that PHP page, but still run the PHP code

Comment: @LuisEspinoza I have already answered my question. Stack Overflow isn't allowing me to accept it for 2 days.

Comment: yes..i after i wrote the comment i noticed that you have already answered the question. it's ok ;D @AshleyStaggs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out! :D

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/json"); ?>
```

Put this at the top of your page before anything is printed on the screen and AFNetworking will recognise it as JSON

Answer (score 2):

@Ashley Thanks for sharing this. I had the same problem and this resolved it. However it should be

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

and not as you state